# Validating a custom themed recaptcha in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, validation, recaptcha

I'm using recaptcha custom theme in ASP.NET following this guide: https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/customization. But the validation (Page.IsValid) always return true no matter what i type in. So how can I properly validate recaptcha in custom theme?